# Installing gogs persistent on minishift

Tags: openshift, gogs, minishift

I'm trying to install gogs on minishift with persistentVolumes.
I did this:

```
c:\> oc login -u system -p admin
c:\> oc new-project cicd
c:\> oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenShiftDemos/gogs-openshift-docker/master/openshift/gogs-persistent-template.yaml
```

from the webconsole I load and execute the imported yaml template and I have gogs and postgresql up and running as you can see in the image below
[image]

Unfortunately, when I try to do this first installation of gogs I stuck in this error:
[image]

I know the issue is that gogs docker can access in write mode on /etc/gogs/conf/ dir.

How can I solve this on minishift?

thx
fabrizio